# Get form from a checkbox that has a name from a SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, forms, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask and sqlalchemy for a project.
Trying to update the column (which is an integer) 'prezenta' of an user, if the checkbox is checked.
How do I get the form of those checkboxes?

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   Nume = db.Column(db.String(100))
   Prenume = db.Column(db.String(100))
   prezenta = db.Column(db.Integer)

   def __init__(self, Nume, Prenume, prezenta):
      self.Nume = Nume
      self.Prenume = Prenume 
      self.prezenta = prezenta
```

I have a table in html with a list of people, I made it using jinja, each row also has a checkbox input, with the name of the person id.
How should my code for python look like if I want to update the 'prezenta' column, increasing it with 1, if the person id checkbox is checked?

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nume</th>
                    <th scope="col">Prenume</th>
                    <th scope="col">Prezenta</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for user in Users %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
                    <td>{{ user.Nume }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.Prenume }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ user.id }}" />
                        {{ user.prezenta }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input
            type="submit"
            name="submit"
            class="btn btn-info btn-md"
            value="Submit"
        />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from checkboxes it gives a answer of 0 or a value that you specify

maybe you want to use a radio button?

also to pass it to flask use:

```
chqbox = request.args.get('user.id')
```

and a "if" to check the value inside the checkbox